# Power BI - If with AND and OR Statements

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following DAX Calculated column formula which isn't executing correctly

```
CheckStatus =
IF('Data'[DaysUntilExpiry] >-100 && 'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry]<=0 && 'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth] <-100 || 'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth]>0, "Check Product")
```

Formula break down:
I have 2 columns: DaysUntilExpiry & DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth.

What I want to do is output "Check Product"

**if**
DaysUntilExpiry is >-100

**AND** DaysUntilExpiry  < 0

**AND**

DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth is <-100

**OR**

DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth >0

The formula works for `DaysUntilExpiry is >-100 AND < 0` But when the second part is added it executes but the output is incorrect.

**Data** Table won't format correctly for me (see pic below)
| DaysUntilExpiry | DaysUntilExpiryPreviousMonth |
| --------------- | ---------------------------- |
| -2              | 1                            |
| -102            | 2                            |
| -5              | -10                          |

**Check Product should only output for the first row.**

[image: Data]
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a parenthesis around your predicate groups, else you will quickly run into issues where your logic is no longer obvious:

```
CheckStatus =
IF (
    'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry] >-100 
      && 'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry]<=0 
      && 
       (
         'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth] <-100 
          || 'Data'[DaysUntilExpiry_PreviousMonth] > 0 
       ),
    "Check Product"
)
```

Edit: I think I got it right this time.. ;)

Edit 2: Works for me. Perhaps you should reconsider how you phrase your question? In any event, this is a simple logic gate. Use parenthesis correctly and your calculations will be correct.

[image]

Comment: thank you however it still isn't working properly. See data and desired output above. I have edited the question

Comment: I have updated my answer - the code is correct for your sample data.

Comment: Great thank you, I'll need to look into the parenthesis. I haven't had to do that before but it worked.